# Using string type to splice strings failed to submit ODBC (SQL) statements

Tags: c++, sql-server, odbc

```
void Insert_Product()
{
    // sql：INSERT INTO product VALUES ('TEST',13)
    ret = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hdbc, &hstmt);
    SQLWCHAR sql1[] = L"USE OrderingSystem";
    //SQLWCHAR sql2[] = L"INSERT INTO product VALUES('TEST',13)";
    string str1 = "INSERT INTO product VALUES ('";
    cout << "Please enter the product name and price in turn." << endl;
    string pname, pprice;
    cin >> pname >> pprice;
    string str2 = str1 + pname + "'," + pprice + ")";
    ret = SQLExecDirect(hstmt, sql1, SQL_NTS);
    ret = SQLExecDirect(hstmt, (SQLWCHAR*)str2.c_str(), SQL_NTS);
    if (ret == SQL_SUCCESS || ret == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
        cout << "SUCCESS!" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "FAIL!" << endl;
        handleResult(hstmt, SQL_HANDLE_STMT, ret);
    }
    error(ret);
}
```

The database connection is success.

If I use **sql2** to submit ODBC statements, the code can work properly.

But when I use **str2** to submit ODBC statements it will fail.

> ErrorMsg:[42000]---[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]??????? '??????????????xe'?---(2812)

It means  SQLSTATE:42000 ERROR CODE:2812 .

The SQL statements can run well in SQL Server.

So why use the **str2** will report an error?

Comment: What value are you trying to insert? Use a parameterized query, otherwise you leave yourself open to SQL injection and syntax errors

Answer (score 0):

```
void Insert_Product()
{
    // sql：INSERT INTO product VALUES ('TEST',13)
    ret = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hdbc, &hstmt);
    string str1 = "INSERT INTO products VALUES ('";
    cout << "Please enter the product name and price in turn." << endl;
    string pname, pprice;
    cin >> pname >> pprice;
    string str2 = str1 + pname + "'," + pprice + ")";

    wchar_t* wc = new wchar_t[str2.size()];
    swprintf(wc, 100, L"%S", str2.c_str()); 

    ret = SQLExecDirect(hstmt, wc, SQL_NTS);
    if (ret == SQL_SUCCESS || ret == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
        cout << "SUCCESS!" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "FAIL!" << endl;
        handleResult(hstmt, SQL_HANDLE_STMT, ret);
    }
    error(ret);
}
```

USE   string->char->wchar_t*

```
    wchar_t* wc = new wchar_t[str2.size()];
    swprintf(wc, 100, L"%S", str2.c_str());
```